# replacement SetDelayed instead of Rule

Tags: functions, syntax

I have the following code:

```
Solve[-(Sin[x]/(α*Gamma[α])) - 
   Subscript[a, 0][x]/(α*Gamma[α]) == 0, 
 Subscript[a, 0][x]]
```

For replacement  `SetDelayed` instead of `Rule`, I rewrite

```
Solve[-(Sin[x]/(α*Gamma[α])) - 
    Subscript[a, 0][x]/(α*Gamma[α]) == 0, 
  Subscript[a, 0][x]] /. Rule -> SetDelayed
```

I want to calculate

```
Sqrt[Pi]*Derivative[2][Subscript[a, 0]][x]
```

But I do not have any output. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For better readability I substituted the subscripted variable with `b`

```
fun = -(Sin[x] / (a Gamma[a])) - b / (a Gamma[a]) // Simplify
```

[image]

```
sol = First[b /. Solve[fun == 0, b]]
```

[image]

Now use `D` instead of `Derivative`

```
Sqrt[Pi] D[sol, {x, 2}]
```

[image]

To get the same result with `Derivative` you would have to write

```
Sqrt[Pi] (-Derivative[2][Sin][x])
```

which is difficult to automate

Answer (score 0):

You can see why studying the Trace:
[image]

The culprit is that what you achieve with your substitution is to evaluate `Subscript[a, 0][x] := -Sin[x]`.

Note that this is an expression of the form `f[x] := foo[x]`, as opposite to `f[x_] := foo[x]`.
In other words, you did not define a function, hence why `Derivative` does not work.

It's the same as doing

```
f[x] := Sin[x]
Derivative[2][f][x]
```

which will not work.

You can use your trick, provided you also convert `x` into `x_`:

```
Solve[
    -(Sin[x]/(\[Alpha]*Gamma[\[Alpha]])) - 
      f[x]/(\[Alpha]*Gamma[\[Alpha]]) == 0,
    f[x]
    ][[1, 1]] // {#[[1]] /. x -> x_, #[[2]]} & // Apply@SetDelayed
```

and then you can use `Derivative` as you wanted (I used `f[x]` instead of `Subscript[a, 0][x]` here, for better readability.

Of course, you don't really need to do these kinds of hacks in the first place. The kind of solution provided by eldo is a better for most circumstances.